# Add data attribute values together and store as a var jQuery

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I'd like to add together all of the `data-score` values in the `<ul>` and store them in a jQuery variable

The amount of `<li>` items would be dynamic

```
<ul id="score_list">
  <li data-score="1">FooBar</li>
  <li data-score="0">FooBar</li>
  <li data-score="0">FooBar</li>
  <li data-score="3">FooBar</li>
  <li data-score="1">FooBar</li>
</ul>
```

TIA

Comment: and what have you tried? Also, there's no thing as a jquery variable.

Comment: @AmitJoki, @connexo  I did attempt to work it out but couldn't quite figure out how to loop through the `<li>` and add the total together. Didn't see the point in showing code that did not work. Apologies if I ruined your afternoon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple as iterating through all your li elements and getting data-score attributes value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = 0;
    $('#score_list > li').each(function(a){
    x = x + +$(this).data('score')
  })
  console.log(x)
});
```

Below are things that you have checked before asking it:

- [How to get value of data attributes.](https://api.jquery.com/data/)
- [How to get element by id](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-item-using-class-or-id/)

Comment: Questions not showing any effort whasoever should **not** be rewarded with an answer.

Comment: You should have checked it before downvoting. I adding a + before getting data-score. Please make sure to check answer correctly before downvoting

Comment: adding a + will convert a string to integer (parse it to integer) and then add it to x

Comment: I downvoted for answering. Getting an answer to a question like this will only encourage OP - and others - to find people coding stuff for them here.

Comment: Well ok. Sorry about that. I will delete the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your working answer @G_S really appreciated! Apologies to everyone else if this was too simple to post - but hey, easy if you know the answer